# ransack search customization using PostgreSQL function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, rails-postgresql, ransack

I have an Order model and a Payments model.

Order has many Payments.

I'm performing a search on the order model using ransack. I have the following association fields for payments in the search form.

payments_created_at_lteq
payments_created_at_gteq

to allow the users to select a payment date range for that order(s).

In this scenario I would get orders repeated for that payment date range due to the has many relation.

What I want is to use some PostgreSQL function like string_agg() in the query so that I can concatenate all the dates for that order so that the order does not repeat. How do I do that using ransack? Is there any way I can customize ransack search or result method to use that PostgreSQL function. Any other ideas are also welcome.

Regards,